# PySpark not able to read json files greater than 2GB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to read a json file from azure blob storage using spark. I am just using the basic syntax.

Here is the code I am using :

```
 df = (
        spark.read
            .option('multiline','true')
          .format("json")
          .load(fp_in)
          .select("type", explode(col("features")).alias("feature"))   
          .select("type",col("feature.properties.*"),(col("feature.geometry")).alias('json_geometry'))
        
    )
```

For the files less than 2GB, the `df` is created. But for files greater than 2GB I am getting the error

`IllegalArgumentException: Cannot grow BufferHolder, exceeds 2147483632 bytes`

Comment: read [this post](https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/sql/cannot-grow-bufferholder-exceeds-size)

Comment: I cannot change the data in the columns and every part is necessary.Is there any other way?